# Need to validate int; hasNextInt isn't working

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework problem of creating a guessing game. I've got that part working, but we have to validate the input. I've tried using hasNextInt, but I keep getting an error saying "int cannot be dereferenced" and points to the "!guess.hasNextInt" code.

I've tried many iterations, but I still get the same error. The code I'm including is just my most recent try.

How do I get hasNextInt to work or how else should I validate the input?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * 101);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to my Guessing Game!");

        int guess = -1;
        //Loop goes as long as guess doesn't equal num
        while (guess != num) {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100:   ");
            guess = input.nextInt();

            //Validates input
            while (!guess.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid response, try again.");
                in.next();
            }

            if (guess == num)
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            else if (guess < num)
                System.out.println("Your guess was too low");
            else
                System.out.println("Your guess was too high");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `guess` is of the primitive type `int`. Therefore you can't call methods on it, such as when you try to call `guess.hasNextInt()`. `hasNextInt()` is a method of the `Scanner` class. Also note that `hasNextInt()` won't serve the purpose of validating the input.

Comment: `.hasNextInt()` is a method of `Scanner` class, you are trying to call it on an `int` variable. You probably meant to use `input` instead of `guess`: `input.hasNextInt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
    System.out.println(num);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to my Guessing Game!");

    int guess = -1;
    //Loop goes as long as guess doesn't equal num
    while (guess != num) {
        System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100:   ");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess == num) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            break;}
        else if (guess < num)
            System.out.println("Your guess was too low");
        else
            System.out.println("Your guess was too high");

        //Validates input
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, try again.");
            input.next();
        }

       
    }
}
```

if the user guessed the number the game ends using `break`

in `while (!guess.hasNextInt())` you were using a integer where it's expect the Scanner `input`

Comment: Great info! I ended up solving it myself right before checking back to see your code. Essentially we both got the end result with a bit of a difference. I'll drop my code below:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse your number you can use Integer.parseInt() method as shown. Also you are using hasNextInt() incorrectly. You are also not storing in.next() value in any variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = (int)(Math.random() * 101);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to my Guessing Game!");

    int guess = -1;
    //Loop goes as long as guess doesn't equal num
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 100:   ");
        String numberString = input.nextLine();

        //Validates input
        try {
            guess = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
            if (guess == num) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                break;
            } else if (guess < num)
                System.out.println("Your guess was too low");
            else
                System.out.println("Your guess was too high");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, try again.");
        }
       }
    }
}
```